# Working with textfieldShouldReturn() for two TextBox

Tags: ios

Hi I started to learning iOS developing but in my first I got a problem 
I have two Text box in first one when I press return button on keyboard go
to next text box I did it well but the problem is this when I am on the second Text box I want after typing when I press return keyboard go away

I cant use two

> textfieldShouldReturn()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell which text box is being called. First, you need to create outlets so that you can reference the two text boxes by name. Then:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   if (textField == self.firstTextField) {
       // Do it one way
   } else if (textField == self.secondTextField) {
       // Do it another way
   }
   return NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks its is really great answer but what is that self exactly?

Comment: `self` is a reference to the viewcontroller instance. `firstTextField` and `secondTextField` are references to textfields.